# Given a $|W_8\rangle$, perform a CCCZ using stabilizer operations

Tags: circuit-construction, stabilizer-state, magic-states

I know it's possible to perform a CCZ operation using only stabilizer operations (Cliffords + Pauli measurements + classical feedback) by consuming a $|CCZ\rangle$ state, and that a $|W_4\rangle$ state can be turned into a $|CCZ\rangle$ state, so I can perform a CCZ using a $|W_4\rangle$. But I've been struggling to find the smallest $|W_n\rangle$ state that can perform a CCCZ deterministically. Initially I thought $|W_8\rangle$ would work, since I can turn it into a $|CCCZ\rangle$ state, but then when I teleport through it I end up with CCZ corrections and no way to do them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to perform a CCCZ by consuming a $|W_{8}\rangle$ state.

The key idea is to use the state $\text{AND}_{1,2} \cdot \text{AND}_{1,3} \cdot \text{AND}_{2,3} \cdot \text{AND}_{1,2,3} \cdot |+\rangle^{\otimes 3}$ (where $\text{AND}$ allocates a $|0\rangle$ qubit and then targets it with a NOT gate controlled by the indicated qubits). This state has enough "bells and whistles" on top of the basic $|CCCZ\rangle$ state that you can perform the corrective CCZs that result from the CCCZ teleportation. And also it's possible to turn a $|W_{8}\rangle$ state into this state using only stabilizer operations. The reason this is possible is because you can think of the $|W_{8}\rangle$ state as a one-hot unary encoding of a uniform superposition, it's possible to go from unary to binary using stabilizer operations, and single controls on the one-hot unary representation act like multiple controls on the binary representation.

[Here is a circuit](https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22%3A%5B%5B%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22Amps7%22%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%7Ee9nr%22%2C%22%7Ee9nr%22%2C%22%7Ee9nr%22%2C%22%7Ee9nr%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C%22H%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C%22X%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C%22X%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22X%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B%22X%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B%22Measure%22%2C%22Measure%22%2C%22Measure%22%2C%22Measure%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C%22Z%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Z%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22Z%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22Z%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Z%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Measure%22%2C%22Measure%22%2C%22Measure%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C%22Z%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22Z%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Z%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Z%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22Z%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C%22Z%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22Z%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C%22Z%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C%22Z%22%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Z%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Z%22%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Z%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%7E2a8a%22%2C%22%7E2a8a%22%2C%22%7E2a8a%22%2C%22%7E2a8a%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%7Ee36t%22%2C%22%7Ee36t%22%2C%22%7Ee36t%22%2C%22%7Ee36t%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Z%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%7Ee36t%22%2C%22%7Ee36t%22%2C%22%7Ee36t%22%2C%22%7Ee36t%22%5D%5D%2C%22gates%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A%22%7Ee9nr%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22input%22%2C%22matrix%22%3A%22%7B%7B1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%7D%7D%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22%7E2a8a%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22output%22%2C%22matrix%22%3A%22%7B%7B1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%7D%7D%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22%7Ee36t%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22check%22%2C%22matrix%22%3A%22%7B%7B1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%7D%7D%22%7D%5D%7D) that prepares the state $\text{AND}_{1,2} \cdot \text{AND}_{1,3} \cdot \text{AND}_{2,3} \cdot \text{AND}_{1,2,3} \cdot |+\rangle^{\otimes 3}$ and then consumes it to perform a CCCZ:

[image]

And [here is a circuit](https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22%3A%5B%5B%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C%22%3E%3E6%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22%3E%3E3%22%5D%2C%5B%22%3E%3E2%22%5D%2C%5B%22X%22%2C%22%E2%97%A6%22%5D%2C%5B%22inputA1%22%2C1%2C%22%5E%3DA1%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C%22Z%22%2C%22%E2%8A%96%22%5D%2C%5B%22%5E%3DA2%22%2C1%2C%22inputA2%22%5D%2C%5B%22inputA3%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%5E%3DA3%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Z%22%2C%22Z%22%2C%22Z%22%2C%22%E2%8A%96%22%5D%2C%5B%22%5E%3DA4%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22inputA4%22%5D%2C%5B%22%7Efu9m%22%2C%22%7Efu9m%22%2C%22%7Efu9m%22%2C%22%7Efu9m%22%2C%22%7Efu9m%22%2C%22%7Efu9m%22%2C%22%7Efu9m%22%2C%22%7Efu9m%22%2C%22Chance%22%2C%22Chance%22%2C%22Chance%22%2C%22Chance%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Z%22%2C%22%E2%8A%96%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Z%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Z%22%2C1%2C%22%E2%8A%96%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Z%22%2C1%2C%22Z%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%8A%96%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Z%22%2C%22Z%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%8A%96%22%5D%2C%5B%22%5E%3DA4%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22inputA4%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Z%22%2C%22Z%22%2C%22Z%22%2C%22%E2%8A%96%22%5D%2C%5B%22inputA3%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%5E%3DA3%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B%22%5E%3DA2%22%2C1%2C%22inputA2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C%22Z%22%2C%22%E2%8A%96%22%5D%2C%5B%22inputA1%22%2C1%2C%22%5E%3DA1%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B%22X%22%2C%22%E2%97%A6%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%3E%3E4%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22%3E%3E5%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%7E8qh%22%2C%22%7E8qh%22%2C%22%7E8qh%22%2C%22%7E8qh%22%2C%22%7E8qh%22%2C%22%7E8qh%22%2C%22%7E8qh%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Amps7%22%5D%5D%2C%22gates%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A%22%7Efu9m%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22W8%22%2C%22matrix%22%3A%22%7B%7B1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%7D%7D%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22%7E8qh%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22out%22%2C%22matrix%22%3A%22%7B%7B1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%7D%7D%22%7D%5D%7D) that turns a $|W_{8}\rangle$ state into the state $\text{AND}_{1,2} \cdot \text{AND}_{1,3} \cdot \text{AND}_{2,3} \cdot \text{AND}_{1,2,3} \cdot |+\rangle^{\otimes 3}$:

[image]

(Note: the circuit has Toffolis inside one of the controlled XOR gates after the W8 state is prepared, but these Toffolis are uncomputing a value so they can be replaced with measurement based uncomputation.)

[Put the two together](https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22%3A%5B%5B%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C%22%3E%3E6%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22%3E%3E3%22%5D%2C%5B%22%3E%3E2%22%5D%2C%5B%22X%22%2C%22%E2%97%A6%22%5D%2C%5B%22inputA1%22%2C1%2C%22%5E%3DA1%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C%22Z%22%2C%22%E2%8A%96%22%5D%2C%5B%22%5E%3DA2%22%2C1%2C%22inputA2%22%5D%2C%5B%22inputA3%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%5E%3DA3%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Z%22%2C%22Z%22%2C%22Z%22%2C%22%E2%8A%96%22%5D%2C%5B%22%5E%3DA4%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22inputA4%22%5D%2C%5B%22%7Efu9m%22%2C%22%7Efu9m%22%2C%22%7Efu9m%22%2C%22%7Efu9m%22%2C%22%7Efu9m%22%2C%22%7Efu9m%22%2C%22%7Efu9m%22%2C%22%7Efu9m%22%2C%22Chance%22%2C%22Chance%22%2C%22Chance%22%2C%22Chance%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Z%22%2C%22%E2%8A%96%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Z%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Z%22%2C1%2C%22%E2%8A%96%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Z%22%2C1%2C%22Z%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%8A%96%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Z%22%2C%22Z%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%8A%96%22%5D%2C%5B%22%5E%3DA4%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22inputA4%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Z%22%2C%22Z%22%2C%22Z%22%2C%22%E2%8A%96%22%5D%2C%5B%22inputA3%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%5E%3DA3%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B%22%5E%3DA2%22%2C1%2C%22inputA2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C%22Z%22%2C%22%E2%8A%96%22%5D%2C%5B%22inputA1%22%2C1%2C%22%5E%3DA1%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B%22X%22%2C%22%E2%97%A6%22%5D%2C%5B%22%3E%3E2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22%3C%3C3%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C%22%3C%3C6%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%3C%3C6%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%3C%3C6%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%3C%3C6%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%3C%3C6%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Chance%22%2C%22Chance%22%2C%22Chance%22%2C%22Chance%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C%22H%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%7Ebgdk%22%2C%22%7Ebgdk%22%2C%22%7Ebgdk%22%2C%22%7Ebgdk%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C%22X%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C%22X%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22X%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B%22X%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B%22Measure%22%2C%22Measure%22%2C%22Measure%22%2C%22Measure%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C%22Z%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Z%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22Z%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22Z%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Z%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Measure%22%2C%22Measure%22%2C%22Measure%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C%22Z%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22Z%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Z%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Z%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22Z%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C%22Z%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22Z%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C%22Z%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C%22Z%22%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Z%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Z%22%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Z%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%7Ej2o2%22%2C%22%7Ej2o2%22%2C%22%7Ej2o2%22%2C%22%7Ej2o2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%7Ejn3c%22%2C%22%7Ejn3c%22%2C%22%7Ejn3c%22%2C%22%7Ejn3c%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Z%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%7Ejn3c%22%2C%22%7Ejn3c%22%2C%22%7Ejn3c%22%2C%22%7Ejn3c%22%5D%5D%2C%22gates%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A%22%7Efu9m%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22start%22%2C%22matrix%22%3A%22%7B%7B1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%7D%7D%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22%7Ebgdk%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22input%22%2C%22matrix%22%3A%22%7B%7B1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%7D%7D%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22%7Ejn3c%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22check%22%2C%22matrix%22%3A%22%7B%7B1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%7D%7D%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22%7Ej2o2%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22output%22%2C%22matrix%22%3A%22%7B%7B1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%7D%7D%22%7D%5D%7D), and you have a circuit that performs a CCCZ by consuming a $|W_8\rangle$ state.